# Periodic word count in margin

Tags: margins, marginpar, word-count

I need to have a continuous word count for an assignment. This is either in the form of a note in the margin or one parenthesised in-text every 100 words or so. For instance,

```
----- TEXT ------|- MARGIN -
blahblahblahblah | 100 [100th word appears on this line]
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: Please provide some more information about the TeX format you use: Plain, eTeX, xeTeX, or LuaTeX.

Comment: What an evil assignment! (I'm tempted to say ridiculous, but there could be extenuating circumstances.)  Also, do you need a *dynamic* word count?  A tex solution would be, but this sounds like you only need this count for when you hand it in.

Comment: Plain TeX. Doesn't need to be dynamic, static is fine. But of course, it would be nice to see it as I edit it. =)

Comment: How accurate does this have to be? what defines "a word"? Do headings count? do footnotes count ... there are a lot of possibilities to complicate it. If from within TeX then probably only through LuaTeX and even there the programming effort would be considerable.

Answer (score 2):

I know a way with the GNU Emacs application, though the limitation is that it can't recognize latex code (maybe someone has a suggestion?), and therefore would only work if it is stripped from latex code at first:

```
C-u 100 M-f         ;; forward-word
M-F
M-W
SPACE               ;; insert space
\                   ;; self-insert-command
marginpar{          ;; self-insert-command * 10
C-y                 ;; yank
}                   ;; self-insert-command
M-b                 ;; backward-word
DEL                 ;; backward-delete-char-untabify
```

Using F4 (call-last-macro) from then on will then do what you ask every 100 words (make sure to put the cursor at the word after the \marginpar{}

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. The code shows the basics of how one could do a word count with xelatex. I understand this is not your setup at all.

```
\usepackage{xesearch}

\newcounter{words}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setcounter{words}{0}
    \SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
        {a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
    \UndoBoundary{'’-}
    \MakeBoundary{„“‚‘–}
    \SearchOrder{p;}
}
\AtEndDocument{
    \StopSearching
    \newpage \thispagestyle{empty}
    \arabic{words} words in document
}
```

It suits my needs to hack a margin note into `\addtokomafont{section}{}`, but I’m not sure how to invoke a command once a counter hits a certain threshold.